# Optimization: find from a flattened recursive structure by index

Tags: javascript, recursion, data-structures

Say I have a structure that looks as follows.

```
[{
  name: 'Prepare the ingredients',
  steps: [{
    name: 'Cut tomatoes',
    steps: [{
      name: 'Peel tomatoes',
    }, {
      name: 'Dice tomatoes',
    }]
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Sautee vegetables',
  steps: [{
    name: 'Put two table spoons of olive oil in pan',
  }]
}]
```

I store a reference to `current` in a database and increment it on each step.

The *first* step is defined as the first step found that has no children. In this case, it would be `{ name: 'Peel tomatoes' }`. The next step is `{ name: 'Dice Tomatoes' }`.

I am having a bit of trouble finding a way to find by index. The only way I have found to manage this is to flatten the entire structure *then* get at an index. I want to return the step and a reference to it's parent element.

```
_flatten(steps, parent) {
  for (let index=0; index<steps.length; index++) {
    if (steps[index].steps instanceof Array) {
      this.steps.push(this._flatten(steps[index].steps, steps[index]));
    }
    this.steps.push(new Step(steps[index], parent));
  }
}
let data = Schedule.findOne({}, { sort: { createdAt: -1 } })  // most recent schedule.
_flatten(data.steps)[data.metadata.steps.current];
```

Is there any appropriate way to optimize this, rather than flattening the entire structure on every search?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a nested reference, i.e. an array of indices. You can trivially traverse your structure with that, as well as do increments, without needing to flatten the entire thing.